# When to raise a nullArg in F#

Tags: .net, exception, f#, option-type, nullable

From [Exceptions (Syntax for throwing and catching)](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/exceptions/), it says there are four useful exception keywords built into F#, with `nullArg` throws a `NullArgumentException`:

```
let f x =
   if x then "ok"
   else nullArg "paramName" "message"
```

If I'm writing modules for F# usage only, when should I raise a `NullArgumentException`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't. Exceptions are bleh. Avoid them. Only use them when interfacing with external code that expects you to throw exceptions or doesn't give you another way to report errors.

Instead, if you're writing a function that may fail, make it return an "either/or" value - either result or an error. Along these lines:

```
type Result<'t, 'e> = Ok of 't | Error of 'e

let f x =
   if x then Ok "ok"
   else Error "boo!"
```

This way, the calling code can't "forget" to handle the error case: the compiler won't let it. This is a Good Thing.

Incidentally, [F# 4.1 includes the `Result` type in the box](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/07/25/a-peek-into-f-4-1/) (and some useful utilities). Check out the example in that post.

Also of interest: [here's](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/) a great series of articles and a presentation video on the subject.

Answer (score 4):

Even when you are writing code just for F# consumption, I think there are perfectly valid cases for using exceptions in F# code.

If you have errors that you expect, then it might be better to use the `Result` type. This include reading data that might be ill-formed (because it comes from the user) or validating user inputs that might be incorrect.

However, I think exceptions are still useful for indicating *exceptional* cases. For `nullArg` specifically, there are not many cases when you'd need it because F# mostly eliminates `null` values, but you can still get one when you are taking a .NET type as an argument. If you have a function taking an `IDictionary<string, string>` and you never expect this to be `null`, it might be useful to write:

```
let lookupName (dict:IDictionary<string, string>) = 
  if dict = null then nullArg "dict" "lookupName expects a valid dictionary!"
  if dict.ContainsKey "name" then dict.["name"] else "anonymous"
```

As `IDictionary` is a .NET type, F# does not make sure that it is never `null` and handling the case explicitly might give you more useful error information in case you do accidentally something wrong in your code.

Comment: If I'm writing a function exclusively for F# consumption, I wouldn't use `IDictionary` in the first place. And even if I'm interfacing with .NET and getting this dictionary from outside,   I would treat it as "external input" and validate it as such, returning a `Result`.

Comment: @MiP - Tomas generally gives excellent advice. However, in this case he's giving advice aimed at people who are relatively familiar with F#, and it sounds like you're still in the learning stage. So for once, I'm going to disagree with Tomas. :-) *At this stage* of your learning F#, you should avoid exceptions entirely, and go with the `Result` type that Fyodor Soikin recommended that you use. Once you've learned F# enough that you *know* when exceptions are more useful than the `Result` type (which is rare, but does occasionally happen), then and only then should you follow Tomas's advice.

Comment: @rmunn Well, I'll weigh in to this in support of Tomas.  I know this exception topic is hotly debated in the F# world but I think it's really quite simple.  If success or failure is part of your API, a simple example would be parsing a string as an int then `Result` is clearly the way to go but there is no benefit of returning `Result` in the null arg case Tomas describes, it will just pollute your API.  You just want to fail hard with a useful error and get the callee to fix their code.

Comment: @theinnerlight if you're writing an F#-exclusive API (as the OP indicated), there is no need to use nullable types, and therefore no occasion to throw `nullArg`. But if you're in general .NET land (which is _not_ the case here), then by all means, do whatever Romans do.

Comment: The question is about `nullArg` specifically, which is quite rarely useful - I picked `IDictionary` simply as an example of one very useful .NET type. Speaking more generally about exceptions, I think polluting all your types with `Result` is a mistake if "invalid result" is not a normal part of your expected public API.

Comment: Nullable types are also not a "normal" thing with F#-only API. So you can twist it both ways.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Your answer doesn't refer to `nullArg` specifically though, you've made a blanket statement about exceptions being bad which I think is too much of a generalisation.  `nullArg` is going to be rarely used in idiomatic F#-only work but I don't think "exceptions are bad, don't use them" is the right message to be sending out more generally.  Results are for failures that are part of the API and Exceptions are for failures that are exceptional.  OO code tends to overuse exceptions for expected failures and that's wrong but it's equally wrong to use `Result` for exceptional failures.

Comment: @TheInnerLight I didn't say "never use them". I said "avoid them", and then offered some specific cases in which they should be used. Wouldn't you agree that one should make every effort to avoid exceptions before resorting to them?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Speaking for myself, I do not think it's right to "make every effort to avoid exceptions". They are one of the tools in the toolbox with advantages (easy to use, automatic propagation) and disadvantages (not type checked). If the advantages outweigh disadvantages, you should use them.

Comment: @tomas I agree with this very general idea about advantages and disadvantages, and I am saying that in the vast majority of cases disadvantages outweigh advantages, and therefore, if one was to have a rule of thumb regarding exceptions, that rule should be "avoid".

Comment: I'm happy we agree on the general idea. Then we'll just need to agree to disagree on the evaluations :-)